# why is the photo_slider.html file i created not displaying the photos after incorporating it into streamlit app?

Tags: python, html, streamlit

I am working on a streamlit app and I want to display photos of some projects on the app. I have implemented a photo slide "photo_slider.html" with HTML and CSS which works fine. I am now trying to incorporate it into the streamlit app but this is the result:[html photo slideshow with background color and next/previous photo buttons showing but images not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocLLW.png)

the images and the photo_slider.html file are saved in a folder called "projects". the projects folder is saved in the same directory as the streamlit file "app.py"

below is code:

```
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image
import requests
from streamlit_lottie import st_lottie
import streamlit.components.v1 as com
import codecs

# ---- PROJECTS SLIDESHOW FUNCTION ----
def st_slideshow(photoslider_html, height=300):
    slideshow_file = codecs.open(photoslider_html, 'r')
    page = slideshow_file.read()
    com.html(page, height=height)
        

# ---- MAIN FUNCTION ----
def main():
    #---- ONGOING PROJECTS ----
    st.markdown("**Ongoing Projects**")
    st_slideshow("projects/photo_slider.html")

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

i would appreciate any help

I am working on a streamlit app and I want to display photos of some projects on the app. I have implemented a photo slide "photo_slider.html" with HTML and CSS which works fine. I am now trying to incorporate it into the streamlit app but i am not getting the desired result.

Comment: Can you share the HTML file as well so we can try to reproduce the issue?